# The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11 is invalid,transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber, pom.xml, tools.jar

I am a newbie to Eclipse.I got this below error when I modified my cucumber project, I added functionality of reading data from excel and writing to excel, until then it worked fine.Tried everything mentioned in other answers.
The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11
[ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${tools.jar} @

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use 2.3.0 version or higher to resolve this error

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Java 6 = JAX-B Version 2.0   -->
    <!-- Java 7 = JAX-B Version 2.2.3 -->
    <!-- Java 8 = JAX-B Version 2.2.8 -->
    <!-- Java 9+ = JAX-B Version 2.3.0 -->
```

Reference:  [github java-logging-support](https://github.com/SAP/cf-java-logging-support/issues/57)

Answer (score -2):

Please re-install your maven dependencies,

1. mvn clean
2. mvn install

your 2.2.11 is existing in the maven repo so reinstalling will resolve your problem

[image]